# Can I delete the CombinedVocalizerVoices file from Mac?

Tags: mac, finder, macos

Can I delete the following directory on my MacBook Air?

```
com_apple_MobileAsset_VoiceServices_CombinedVocalizerVoices
```

which is located at:

```
/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_VoiceServices_CombinedVocalizerVoices
```

It's over half a GB as shown in the Finder screenshot below and I can't find much info about its use online.

[image]

Comment: @Alper thanks for the response. It's 566.5 MB or 566,460,346 bytes to be exact, haha

Comment: I now see that I have an xml file which is 59 KB too, but I am talking about the folder which it is in - that folder is 565 MB, and contains the 59 KB file, as well as a 142.5 MB `.asset` file and a 423.9 MB `.asset` file

Comment: When I press Command+I on the folder containing that file in the Finder, it is shown to be of size 59 KB as well. Are you using the Finder or the Terminal app to get the sizes? Care to share a screenshot from the Finder or, if from Terminal, preferably the text form of the command you are using and its output?

Comment: Might it be the 'speech' voices from Accessibility? I just checked a Monterey Mac with no speech ever used & that file is also 59KB. [It doesn't exist back in Mojave, btw]

Comment: Sure thing @Alper , I'm using the finder app.

https://i.imgur.com/pLCaLzY.png

Comment: Is there a particular problem you’re trying to solve by deleting these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend against removing **anything** in /System—and you can’t do it without disabling SIP.  I especially [recommend against removing this](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/v19w5i/anyone_seen_this_error_query_for/) if you do any IOS programming.

Comment: Generally I go by this rule but this one irks me because of how large it is (relative to the millions of byte-sized files found in /System) and the fact that it really might be useless for me. However, I do plan on tinkering with iOS programming soon so this might be the right call.

I'm quite new to StackExchange so I'm not totally sure, but should I mark this answer as accepted? I might have accidentally [done the xy mistake...](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Well, currently it's the only answer, but maybe wait a day or two and see whether a better one appears.

Comment: @feelThisMoment See [the guideline on accepting an answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) in Ask Different for more if you like.